# cannot open source file "limits"

Tags: c++, c, iar

I'm working on a `C++` project and now porting some functions to `C`. The project works well when I'm using the `cpp` files, however, when I include the `C` files in the project, the compiler is unable to find certain headers like `<limits>`, `<algorithm>` etc.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Those are C++ only headers. You cannot include them in C code. Why do you think you need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C versions of `<limits>` are called `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>` respectively. They are not code compatible with the funcions in C++ `<limits>` but serve the same purposes.

`<algorithm>` is a pure C++ library header and cannot be used in C programs. If your code relies on features from `<algorithm>`, they will have to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: <limits> and <limits.h> are not the same header. I guess you're thinking of <limits.h> and <climits>

Comment: Clarified the confusion about `<limits>`.

Comment: my project is using both C and C++. I'm writing some functions in C for speed improvements. However, these functions rely on some custom header files which contain <limits> and <algorithm>. As soon as I add these C files to the project, the compiler is unable to find <limits> and <algorithm>. Is there any way to make the C functions work without touching the header files that I already have in the project?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - almost all C code can be compiled as C++; there's no speed benefit from compiling such code as C.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: No, if the files use the C++ library, then you'll have to either leave them as C++ or rewrite the necessary library functions in C. You're unlikely to get any speed improvements from rewriting in C.